# The public static HashMap instance returns NULL when accessed from another class , even though I populate the values in constructor

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to create a dictionary to learn Java which will read the words predefined in `wordlist.txt` as

```
subterfuge:something intended to misrepresent the true nature of an activity
stymie:thwarting and distressing situation;
```

But when I try to access the map instance of `ReadToHashmap` class which is declared as `public static`, it allows me to access  However it always returns `null`.

How can I access the map instance with all the the `HashMap` updated as per the `wordlist.txt`?

```
public class ReadToHashmap {
    public static   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ReadToHashmap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static Map getHasMap()
    {
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Maxs\\workspace\\Dictionary\\src\\wordlist.txt"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String parts[] = line.split(":");
                map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }       
            in.close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Erro " +e.getMessage());
        }      



        Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }

        findMeaning word = new findMeaning();
        String inputWord;
        String outputWord;
        System.out.println("Enter rge word to be searched  " );
        inputWord = word.getTheWord();
        outputWord =word.getFromDictionary(inputWord);
        System.out.println("Thge meaning is  " +outputWord);
    }
}
```

Another class

```
public class findMeaning {
    public String inputWord;
    public String description;
    findMeaning()
    {
        inputWord = "";
    }
    public String getTheWord()
    {

        BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try{
            inputWord = br.readLine();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while reading " +e.getMessage() );    
            return "";
        }
        return this.inputWord;
    }

    public String getFromDictionary(String key){

        System.out.println("The output " +ReadToHashmap.getHasMap().toString());    
        if(inputWord.isEmpty())
        {
            return "No lattest input from user ";

        }
        description = (String) ReadToHashmap.getHasMap().get(inputWord);
        if(description == null) 
        {
            return "Word Doesnot exsist";
        }
        return description;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main method populates the map, then iterates through all its entries and removes each of them. So obviously, after this loop, the map is empty.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine after removal of it.remove().
That was silly mistakes from my side.

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote, which makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be removing every entry within the HashMap before you use it in your other class.

```
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove(); // ***** here *****
    }
```

Don't do this.

Other issues: using a static field in this way is not a good idea, and can lead to hard to debug errors. Much better if you create well encapsulated classes that interact with each other in a clean object-oriented fashion.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine after removal of it.remove().
That was silly mistakes from my side.